# athena query return column name as a result set

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

Hi I have just created a schema in AWS ATHENA as follow

```
Create table test (BATCHJOBID  bigint,
CONFIGRECID  bigint,
ENDDATETIME string,
ENDDATETIMETZID  int,
INTJNLID string,
INTJNLTBLRECID  bigint,
PROCESSINGSTATUS  int,
STARTDATETIME string,
STARTDATETIMETZID int,
INTJNLIDBLOCKING string,
RECVERSION int,
PARTITION  bigint,
RECID bigint)
```

But when I am query S3 csv file data

```
Select * from test
```

it return all the value including additional row which are the column name where data type are string.

What could be wrong in DDL statement which returning column(string Type) name as  result set

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this is the ResultSet structure Amazon has chosen for its Javascript SDK, and there is no way to change it.

The JDBC driver, for example, does not have this behavior.

Comment: If I change data type from string to other type it does not appearing on the result set. Do you think it is kind of bug

Comment: I cannot confirm that I'm also using int columns and they get transferred as 'VarCharValue'.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still very new to Athena. From the [AWS Athena docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/glue-best-practices.html#schema-csv-headers): "If you are writing CSV files from AWS Glue to query using Athena, you must remove the CSV headers so that the header information is not included in Athena query results" and goes on show how a Glue ETL job can transform the file to strip the headers. I realize the question is about Athena NOT Glue but I suppose the header guidance may still apply.